# Column not found database error in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I'm doing my first project using Laravel 8, I keep on getting errors of database.  I tried running the migration commands but it didn't fix the problem.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'idfiliere' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `group` (`libelle`, `idfiliere`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (libe1, 2, 2022-04-05 12:18:37, 2022-04-05 12:18:37))

This is the `group` migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Group extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('group', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("idgroup");
            $table->string("libelle");
            $table->foreignId("filiere_id")->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('group');
    }
}
```

And this is the `filiere` migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Filiere extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('filiere', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("idfiliere");
            $table->string("filiere");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('filiere');
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear and correct: your `group` table does not have an `idfiliere` field.  The problem is with the code that is trying to make that insert.

Comment: well my group has the idfiliere   thats the group model <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'group';
    protected $primaryKey = 'IDGroup"';
    protected $fillable = ['IDGroup"','libelle', 'idfiliere'];
}

Comment: Look at your migration.  There is no `idfiliere` column in your `group` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the corresponding Model for your migration. Laravel documentation says that you should specify either a fillable or guarded property on your model class before using a create method. Check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

You should have a $fillable variable with the fields you want to assign a value to. Something like this:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'idfiliere',
    ];
```

Comment: i eventually have the model   <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class filiere extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'filiere';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idfiliere';
    protected $fillable = ['idfiliere','filiere'];
}

Comment: That is the model for your "filiere" table. However the error occures while inserting in the "group" table. From your Group migration, it seems that you are trying to insert data in the "idfiliere" column while you defined a "filiere_id" instead.

Comment: If you have $fillable = ['idfiliere']; in your Group Model, then you should change it to $fillable = ['filiere_id']; and replace 'idfiliere' by 'filiere_id' in the insertion code for your group table

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting data, please check the field in  two table columns. First one is "group" table and Second one is "filiere" table.There is no "idfiliere" field in group table.But filiere table contain the "idfiliere" field.